# Image position inside pill element

Tags: css

[image]

I need the image to be sticked to left and occupy entire corner without taking spacing in top and bottom.Below is the CSS used for the chip and for the image inside chip.

```
.imgDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 -25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You used `padding: 0 25px;` and now you have to fight it by hardcoding margins, negative margins, line heights etc etc. Don't. Use flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily and purely with CSS **flexbox**:

```css
.UserPill {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font: 16px/1.6 sans-serif;
  gap: 10px;
}

.UserPill-img {
  height: 2.4em;
  width: 2.4em;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.UserPill-remove {
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="UserPill">
  <img class="UserPill-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100">
  <span class="UserPill-name">Chris Morris</span>
  <button class="UserPill-remove" type="button" arial-label="Remove">&#x2716;</button>
</div>

<div class="UserPill">
  <img class="UserPill-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg?s=328&g=1">
  <span class="UserPill-name">Roko</span>
  <button class="UserPill-remove" type="button" arial-label="Remove">&#x2716;</button>
</div>

<div class="UserPill">
  <img class="UserPill-img" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IdYKeLCNsyQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucmgTYg8zk2oLDC9ZC0NM8sFu23r3g/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=328">
  <span class="UserPill-name">Anto Clinton</span>
  <button class="UserPill-remove" type="button" arial-label="Remove">&#x2716;</button>
</div>

<div class="UserPill">
  <img class="UserPill-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGiQc.jpg?s=128&g=1">
  <span class="UserPill-name">Amirreza Amini</span>
  <button class="UserPill-remove" type="button" arial-label="Remove">&#x2716;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: nice Roko. lol! does he want to apply the rounded img occupy the whole space? or just like your answer?

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini wooops I was playing around and forgot that one! Thank you for mentioning!

Answer (score -2):

I could get what you mean a bit. I think you want something like this. I don't know why you applied padding to `.imgDiv`, I deleted that. I think you applied it because of the width, use *width* instead.

```css
.imgDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  /* EDITED HERE (USE WIDTH INSTEAD)
  padding: 0 25px;*/
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* RIGHT DOWN BELOW */
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.img {
  float: left;
  /* EDITED HERE (DELETED)
  margin: 0 10px 0 -25px; */
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='imgDiv'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' class='img'>
  <span>Chris Moris</span>
  <span>&#x2715;</span>
</div>
```